# Will shortening file names improved web server response?

Tags: asp.net, database, web-applications, webserver

I'm currently recreating a web application because of performance issues being the web app slows down to a crawl cause of so many files. It enables users to view,upload and download files. Currently there are 600000+ files stored on the server. Each having 100+character long filenames. Will renaming them to shorter names improve performance ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

filelenght shouldn't cause performance problems.

What you can do is (if feasible)

- divide your files to logical segments (read directories)
- crawl conditionally based on some inputs so that , the number of files you crawl will be less.
- Or, try building a cache to record file changes as and when they happen , so that you can read (/crawl) only affected files.